# How to fix: Exception thrown: read access violation. **_Pnext** was 0xFDFDFE05

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to "build" a house which contains rooms. My teacher told me to do it with composition. My idea was to generate as many Rooms objects as many rooms my house has. I tried it with the following code but in the house.cpp's constructor my for cycle runs only once than it crashes at the line rooms[i] = load; with Exception thrown: read access violation.
**_Pnext** was 0xFDFDFE05.

Here's my code:

main.cpp:
'''

```
#include <iostream>  
#include "House.h"  
#include "Rooms.h"

using namespace std;

int main()  
{  
    Rooms basic("basic");  
    House house(basic,2);  
    house.setRooms();  
    house.setWhichroom(1);  
    cout << house.getRooms().getRoomname();  

    return 0;  
}
```

'''
house.h:
'''

```
#pragma once  
#include <iostream>  
#include <string>  
#include "Rooms.h"  

using namespace std;  

class House  
{  
    Rooms* rooms;  
    unsigned roomcount;  
    unsigned whichroom = 0;  
 
public:  

    House();  
    House(const Rooms&, unsigned);  
    House(unsigned);  
    ~House();  
    void setRoomcount(unsigned);  
    unsigned getRoomcount()const;  
    void setWhichroom(unsigned );  
    unsigned getWhichroom()const;  
    void setRooms();  
    Rooms getRooms()const;  

};
```

'''
house.cpp:
'''

```
#include "House.h"  

House::House(const Rooms& load, unsigned rc)  
{  
    roomcount = rc;  
    for (int i = 0; i < roomcount; i++)  
    {  
        rooms = new Rooms;  
        rooms[i] = load;  
    }  
}  

House::House(unsigned x):roomcount(x)  
{  
}  

House::~House()  
{  
    roomcount = 0;  
    delete rooms;  
}  

void House::setRoomcount(unsigned x)  
{  
    roomcount = x;  
}  

unsigned House::getRoomcount() const  
{  
    return roomcount;  
}  

void House::setWhichroom(unsigned x)  
{  
    whichroom = x;  
}  
  
unsigned House::getWhichroom() const  
{  
    return whichroom;  
}  

void House::setRooms()  
{  
    for (unsigned i = 1; i <= roomcount; i++)  
    {  
        char c = i;  
        string s = "room";  
        s += c;  

        rooms[i].setRoomname(s);  
    }  
}  

Rooms House::getRooms() const  
{  
    return rooms[whichroom];  
}
```

'''
rooms.h:
'''

```
#pragma once  
#include <iostream>  
#include "Things.h"  

using namespace std;  

class Rooms  
{  
protected:  

    string roomname;  
    Things things;  

public:  

    Rooms();  
    Rooms(string);  
    ~Rooms();  
    void setRoomname(string);  
    string getRoomname()const;  
    void setThings();  
    unsigned getThings()const;  
};
```

'''
rooms.cpp:

'''

```
#include "Rooms.h"  

Rooms::Rooms()  
{  
}  

Rooms::Rooms(string name)  
{  
    roomname = name;  
}  

Rooms::~Rooms()  
{  
}  

void Rooms::setRoomname(string name)  
{  
    roomname = name;  
}  

string Rooms::getRoomname() const  
{  
    return roomname;  
}  
 
void Rooms::setThings()  
{  
    things.setOnoff();  
}  

unsigned Rooms::getThings() const  
{  
    return things.getOnoff();  
}
```

'''

Comment: To find the problem, run your program in the debugger, step through line by line, and watch out for unexpected changes of variables.

Comment: Time to learn how to use a *debugger* to catch crashes in your programs. When you catch the crash, you can locate where in your program it happens, as well as examine variables and their values at the time of the crash. If you already know the location in your program, then please add a comment in the code, and also tell us the values of the variables.

Comment: `Rooms* rooms;` Change this to `std::vector<Rooms> rooms;`, then get rid of all of your destructors you have now, plus remove all calls to `new[]` and `delete[]`.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the `House` constructor, where you have

```
for (int i = 0; i < roomcount; i++)  
{  
    rooms = new Rooms;
    rooms[i] = load;  
}
```

You will create *one single* `Rooms` object, but treat it as an array of multiple rooms.

You *also* create and create and create new `Room` objects each iteration of the loop, making you loose the earlier objects.

The simple solution, if you need to continue to use explicit memory handling yourself, is to allocate the objects *once* and *before* the loop:

```
rooms = new Rooms[roomcount];
for (int i = 0; i < roomcount; i++)  
{  
    rooms[i] = load;  
}
```

Since you now use `new[]` you must match it with a `delete[]` in the destructor. And you need to learn about [the rules of three and five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

---

To simplify your code I implore you to use a `std::vector` instead, as that will make life so much simpler for you as a C++ programmer.